# Determine the partial derivative of $\frac{\ln \left(x^2y^2\right)\tan \left(\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right)+\sqrt[3]{x^2+y^2}}{\cos ^2\left(x^2y^2\right)}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

> Determine the partial derivative of $f(x)$:
> $$f(x,y)=\frac{\ln \left(x^2y^2\right)\tan \left(\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right)+\sqrt[3]{x^2+y^2}}{\cos ^2\left(x^2y^2\right)}$$

Here's what I have so far:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:x}\left(\frac{\ln \left(x^2y^2\right)\tan \left(\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right)+\sqrt[3]{x^2+y^2}}{\cos ^2\left(x^2y^2\right)}\right) &= \frac{\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:x}\left(\ln \left(x^2y^2\right)\tan \left(\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right)+\sqrt[3]{x^2+y^2}\right)\cos ^2\left(x^2y^2\right)-\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:x}\left(\cos ^2\left(x^2y^2\right)\right)\left(\ln \left(x^2y^2\right)\tan \left(\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right)+\sqrt[3]{x^2+y^2}\right)}{\left(\cos ^2\left(x^2y^2\right)\right)^2} \\
&= \frac{\left(\frac{2\tan \left(\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right)}{x}-\frac{2x\ln \left(y^2x^2\right)\sec ^2\left(\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right)}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}+\frac{2x}{3\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}}\right)\cos ^2\left(x^2y^2\right)-\left(-2y^2x\sin \left(2y^2x^2\right)\right)\left(\ln \left(x^2y^2\right)\tan \left(\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right)+\sqrt[3]{x^2+y^2}\right)}{\left(\cos ^2\left(x^2y^2\right)\right)^2} \\
&= \frac{\cos ^2\left(x^2y^2\right)\left(\frac{2\tan \left(\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right)}{x}-\frac{2x\ln \left(x^2y^2\right)\sec ^2\left(\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right)}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}+\frac{2x}{3\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}}\right)+2xy^2\sin \left(2x^2y^2\right)\left(\ln \left(x^2y^2\right)\tan \left(\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right)+\sqrt[3]{x^2+y^2}\right)}{\cos ^4\left(x^2y^2\right)}
\end{align}

However, I am not sure if this answer is correct since I get a different answer on emathhelp website.

Comment: $f$ is a function of $x$ only, the derivative is not partial.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Sorry that was a typo. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only issue is that  $ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \cos^2(x^2 y^2)$ should be equal to

$$- 4 x y^2 \cos(x^2 y^2) \sin(x^2 y^2) $$

and with that correction it is good.

Comment: Totally missed that. Thank you!